# Why not use Neodymium magnets in cyclotrons?

Tags: magnetic-fields, estimation, particle-accelerators

I am wondering if we can make relatively strong cyclotrons /200-400MeV/ far less massive, in the range 10-20t. Why don't we use neodymium magnets in cyclotrons instead of electromagnets? Nd2Fe14B sintered has a magnetic flux density of approx. 1,2T compared to 1,8T of an electromagnet for a 400MeV/u cyclotron? I am guessing it's because with permanent magnets we can't alter the strength of the field. But if we want a constant output energy of the partciles a permanent magnet should be ok?

Comment: Based on the diagrams I see, the cyclotron requires a N on one side and a S on the other side facing the cyclotron. Since opposites attract, I think it would take a lot of force to prevent two hypothetical neodymium cyclotron magnets from merging with each other. As you know, we need that small gap between the two magnets put the actual cyclotron inside. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/cyclot.html or search the keyword "cyclotron magnet" and see the diagrams for yourself.

Comment: Honestly, I think for lower power applications a C-shaped magnet would work just fine, but at greater strengths, I don't think the magnet's structure would hold (don't quote me on this though).